# automating header file manipulation C/C++ -> C#

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, matlab, visual-c++, pinvoke

I am generating some C code using the Matlab coder, which is then ultimately consumed by a C# application in VS 2010. To be able to do this I have to manually change parts of certain header files (i.e. the ‘interfaces’ being consumed) from:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
extern real_T add(real_T a, real_T b);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

to

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
extern __declspec(dllexport) add(real_T a, real_T b);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

This can be quite tedious if I have to do this for several header files after re-generating the C code. Is there an easy way to automate the process?

Please note that I am not a C/C++ programmer. The C/C++ code is just used as ‘inter mediator’ due to some other requirements. Any feedback very much welcome.

PS:

Please note that I am mainly looking for a visual studio 2010 solution (macro?). I could always write a little C#/Matlab program to achieve all this but I feel that would be overkill.

Comment: find/replace dialog of VS supports regular expressions, doesnt it?

Comment: Isn't there a way to customize MATLAB Coder (maybe with Embedded Coder) so that it generates the headers you want? Manually modifying automatically generated code is not good practice.

Comment: that would be great - answers on a post card please

Comment: It seems to be impossible to change the content of a source file via a macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MATLAB, you can use replacement-by-regular-expression (`regexprep`):

```
% This is obtained by textscan() or load() or similar. 
haystack = {
    '#ifdef __cplusplus'
    'extern "C" {'
    '#endif'
    'extern real_T add(real_T a, real_T b);'
    '#ifdef __cplusplus'
    '}'
    '#endif'
    '#endif'
};

% Search query
needle = '^extern\s*real_T\s*add\(real_T\s*a,\s*real_T\s*b\).*$'

% Replacement 
pin = 'extern __declspec(dllexport) real_T add(real_T a, real_T b);';

% Replace all needles with pins
C = regexprep(haystack, needle, pin);
```

This particular `needle` also finds occurrences that have an arbitrary number of spaces in between all the statements. You could change it to

```
needle = '^extern\s*real_T\s*add\(real_T\s*\w*,\s*real_T\s*\w*\).*$'
```

if also the names `a` and `b` can be different in each header.

Note that this can be done inside a loop, where the loop is over all files obtained by `dir('*.h')` or similar, and each iteration loads a new `haystack` by virtue of `textscan()` or similar. Something like this:

```
% all relevant files
files = dir('*.h');

% Loop over all files
for ii = 1:numel(files)

    % Load the file
    fid = fopen(files(ii).name, 'r');
       haystack = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter', '\n');    
       haystack = haystack{1};
    fclose(fid);

    % do the replacement here
    % ...

end
```

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy answer. I was more looking for a Visual Studio 'solution' (macro?). Sorry I should have made this clearer ...

Comment: I think both you and the OP forgot the function return type. I applaud your solution sticking with MATLAB, but I would have done it in the shell instead (sed or awk)

Comment: @Amro: me too, but since the OP apparently knows MATLAB, and tagged this with "Visual Studio 2010", I assumed no POSIX shell would be available :)

Comment: @csetzkorn: Doesn't Visual Studio have an option to "replace text in all open files"? If so, just open all relevant headers in VS2010 and replace all occurrences with the replacement...If not in VS2010, Notepad++ has the option I believe, as well as a bunch of other editors. I'm sure it's possible to make a sort of single-click solution inside your VS2010 project out of this, but as this feels like a fix/workaround, I wouldn't go any further than simple scripts and/or "smart" manual replacement.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah it is possible but you still have to open them. May have to do this several times a day which can be tiring. Just had a look into VS macros - seems to be a no go. May have to use scrip/program after all ... Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I'll accept you answer. I ended up writing a C# console app which I can run in VS.